# Arch Linux kernel version not changing even after upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel

I have currently Linux `4.10.13-1` kernel installed on my arch. If I install `linux-lts` or upgrade the `linux` package using `pacman`, a folder with the corresponding kernel version name is created in `/lib/modules` as should be but Xorg fails to run because it still looks for drivers in  `/lib/modules/4.10.13-1-ARCH/`. Also, even after the upgrade, the terminal still shows the linux version as `4.10.13-1` instead of the upgraded one. How do I fix this?
Edit: The problem occurs after I reboot.
Update: The problem occured because I use `systemd-boot`. So while upgrading, `/boot` needs to be mounted so that `vmlinuz` can be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot. You will continue to use the old kernel until the system is rebooted. The files on disk have been changed to the new version so once your system starts up again it will be running the new kernel version.

You *could* use [kexec](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kexec) to swap out the currently running kernel without fully rebooting - but I think that restarts all the services anyway and might cause other issues if not done correctly.

Comment: This problem happens after rebooting. Works fine before rebooting.

Comment: @shauryagupta: It’s good to respond to answers with comments (like the above), but, when an answer reveals a misunderstanding of the circumstances of the question, and your comment clarifies it, then you should also [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/393199/edit) to make it clearer and more complete for the benefit of future readers.  They shouldn’t have to read through all the comments under all the answers to figure out exactly what the problem is. Also, consider that Michael could delete his answer — then your comment would be lost.